# Will Apple accept an app that requires a code or PIN to use?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval

I'm working on an iOS app and would like to make it easy for a selected group of non-technical users to quickly download and try it. I won't have their UDIDs ahead of time, nor is TestFlight a viable option because it takes too long to set up. My company isn't large enough to qualify for the Enterprise option, either.

What I'm wondering is: can I submit an app to Apple that requires the user to enter a code at launch? Then I can simply give that code to my demo users (and to Apple for review) and submit it to the store. Or will Apple reject something like that?

Thanks.

Comment: How many users? Why not just do an [ad hoc distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH31-SW3)?

Comment: Paypal accepts PINs so I don't see why you can't. ;)

Comment: What do you mean your company isn't large enough to qualify for Enterprise? My company is just a small handful of devs, and we have an Enterprise account.

Answer (score 3):

The entering of a PIN is not a problem (lots of apps use PIN numbers to protect a user's own data, such as a password vault), but it seems that if the intent is to limit the audience of the app, then that that might run afoul of section 2.22 of the [app store guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html).

If the purpose is testing for a limited number of users, can you just do [ad hoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011159-CH31-SW3) distribution?

Comment: Perhaps my choice of the term PIN was ill-advised. The intent is, indeed, to limit the audience to people I choose. Consider this scenario: I'm meeting a potential investor or advisor and want her to see the app. The demo is far less compelling on my phone, with my data, than on hers. The amount of time required to grab her UDID and add it to an ad hoc build is just prohibitive in that situation.

Section 2.22 seems open to interpretation: it talks about limiting access arbitrarily, a in via carrier or location. Where as I'd be limiting it very explicitly and deliberately based on individual.

Comment: I hear you, but I'd be surprised if Apple would accept it. Section 2.22 says they may reject apps "that arbitrarily restrict which users may use the app", and merely use the location/carrier as examples. And can you imagine what a train wreck the store would be if every conceptual proof of concept app was out there, locked by some PIN? The store just isn't designed to deal with this. I'd personally do a slick video of the app, put it on a password protected mobile-enabled web site. And if you go to the next level, then you can install it on their device.

Answer (score 1):

For demonstrating our apps to clients, my company uses our [iOS Enterprise account](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/). With that account (which costs $299/year instead of $99/year), we can make builds that we can distribute through our own restricted channels, instead of the App Store. Those builds are signed with an **Enterprise Distribution provisioning profile**, which does not require specifying which devices will be used.

After that, we simply restrict who has access to download our app. We use [Testflight](http://testflightapp.com/dashboard/) for this. It enables us to upload our provisioned app, and allows us to invite specific users to download the app. The process of downloading the app is easy enough even for our non-technical clients.

But since you said you don't want to use Testflight, you can distribute your Enterprise apps however you find to be easiest.